# Adding subproject using relative path

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to add a subproject into Master project using VBA.

I have every project in different folder. I can't figure out how to get any kind of "relative" path to it and how to find out if project is or is not into Master project.

I tried following MS Project documentation but there is almost nothing about this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have got every project in different folder

FYI: standard practice is to have the master and subprojects in the same folder.

> I can't figure out how to get any kind of "relative" path to it

The path to subprojects is always the full path. Project does not use relative paths.

> how to find out if project is or is not into Master project

This code will list out (in the Immediate window) the full name of each of the subprojects. Compare the output list to your list of projects.

```
Sub ListSubprojects()

    Dim s As Subproject
    For Each s In ActiveProject.SubProjects
        Debug.Print s.Path
    Next s
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I know the standard of having everything in one folder, but my boss want it that way so I have to keep it like that.